# Hmisc and LaTeX multicloumn

Tags: latex, hmisc

I am trying to create a multicolumn in a LaTeX table. It's easy to do this manually but I create these tabled from data frames generated fro many reports so doing it manually is time consuming. What I have is :

```
cat(cfrm, file="table2.tex") # this categotises the file
t2<-latex(tabl2, file="table2.tex", cellTexCmds = cellTex, rowname=NULL, colheads=c(paste("Recent Average Catch (",minyear," - ",maxyear,")",sep=""), "Skipjack", "Yellowfin","Bigeye","SP Albacore"),  
          caption=paste("Key fishery statistics averaged from ",minyear," to C$_{latest}$ for each of the four main target tunas. Where C$_{latest}$ is the last year in each species assessment model. \\label{tab2}", sep=""), caption.lot=NULL, caption.loc='top', 
          longtable=TRUE, collabel.just=c("c","c","c","c","c"), size="small", 
          col.just=c("l","c","c","c","c"), colnamesTexCmd=c("apple") , append=TRUE)
```

which fives me the table attached:
[image]

What I would like to do is set the blue rows to be a multicolumn.